# why primitive types (eg. number) are assignable to object types(e.g. Number) but not vice versa?

Tags: typescript, primitive-types, object-type

TLDR version:

Why does TypeScript allow the following

```
let num: Number = new Number(1);
num = 1;
```

But does not allow this

```
let num: number = 1;
num = new Number(1)
```

---

It is a well-known fact that JS has two string-like, number-like values.

```
let primNum = 1;
let objNum = new Number(1);

let primString = "str";
let objString = new String("str");
```

And everybody is well advised to do not confuse these, and strongly prefer the primitive versions.

TypeScript is the statically types superset of Javascript that tries to minimize type errors. If there are values that one might confuse and the operation leads to flakey result TS shows the error at compile time. For example, consider the difference between `1 + 1 + "1"`  and `"1" + 1 + 1`. In JavaScript the first value evaluates to `21` and the second one to `111`.
From JS perspective, you can add any two value. You can add two strings, two numbers, a number and a string a so on without problem.However this behaviour is confusing and TypeScript eliminates the possible confusion by refusing to compile when the operands of `+` are not both string or both number. Important point is that even though some JS code out there might expect to be able to add any two things or such an expectation might be rare but it does not matter TS draws the line and does not allow such an operation.

Yet TypeScript has no qualms with the following,

```
let num: Number = new Number(1);
num = 1;
```

First we declare the `num` to be an object type (in TypeScript terms a `Number`) but we assign that variable a primitive type ( in TS terms a `number`) later. This is a confusion that should be caught by TS but TS allows it even without a warning. So one might hypothesize that TS does not make a distinction between `Number` and `number`. (we might not like the decision to not distinguish them but at least in that case we know what we are working with)

But that is not correct either. TS correctly gives error for the following:

```
let num: number = 1;
num = new Number(1)
```

Which means one can assign a `number` to a `Number` but not vice versa? So, the main question is that if TS can distinguish between `number` and `Number` why does it allow one to assign a `Number` to a `number`. Why not disallow both assignments?

Is this a bug? if not, what is the design decision behind this?

TS does not currently have a specification but an old archived one says that

> For purposes of determining subtype, supertype, and assignment compatibility relationships, the Number, Boolean, and String primitive types are treated as object types with the same properties as the ‘Number’, ‘Boolean’, and ‘String’ interfaces respectively.

If this is true we should be able assign a `number` to a `Number` (which we can), but also we should be able to do the opposite. Which means that this old document does not catch up with how TS works currently. The question is what is the current actual rule that determines the subtype relationship between primitive and object types.

One might disagree with such a rule based on the idea that whatever it is it does not eliminate the confusion between `number` and `Number` but that is not the point. The point is it is not clear what even that rule is.

The main question: what is the rule that determines when a primitive type is a subtype of another type?

Similar questions asked in StackOverflow but all answers explain the difference between number primitive types and number object types, and recommend that one avoids the object version. But here the question is not about JavaScript values but about TypeScript's type system. The question is on what basis are the primitive types and object types compared? and this question is not a duplicate of any that has been answered.

Comment: Imagine it like `int` is extending `Number`. You can assign an `int` value to a `Number` type variable, but trying to assign a `Number` to an `int` type variable will fail, because `int` is higher in the hierarchy than the pure `Number` type

Comment: I see your point, but it does not answer the question but just repeats it. I observed that `number` is assigable to `Number` since assignment only succeds when one is the subtype of the other it imples that `number` is a subtype of `Number`. But the question why is it so? For example, Java has the same distinction between primitive types and object types (what they call boxed types) and neither is a subtype of the other. The question is why did TS made such a design choice given that it is highly problematic. Does the answer have to do anything with TS having structural vs Java nominal type

Comment: If you could boil this down to one question what would that be? I'm having a hard time finding that question. Is it _"why does it allow one to assign a `Number` to a `number`"_? Because that's not true: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgSwOYDkYF4ZgKYHcYoCuAtnNgE4AUAjAEwDMAlALABQoksExIANigC4sJMuQzxkaAPRSK5EOSA

Comment: the question is why does it allow to assign a `number` to a `Number`

Answer (score 2):

##### Important Note:

Don't use the `Number` constructor. What follows is assuming you are disregarding that very good advice.

---

I think your asking why this is allowed:

```
const bigN: Number = 123 // fine
```

When this is not:

```
const smallN: number = new Number() // error
```

And you expect both would be an error.

---

The answer is that you can use a `number` as a `Number` without ever noticing the difference. But you *cannot* use a `Number` as a `number` without changing how `number` works.

Look at [this note on MDN about the `Number` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#constructor)

> When `Number` is called as a constructor (with `new`), it creates a `Number` object, which is not a primitive. For example, `typeof new Number(42) === "object"`, and `new Number(42) !== 42` (although new `Number(42) == 42`).
>
> Warning: You should rarely find yourself using `Number` as a constructor.

For instance, note that:

```
new Number(42) !== 42
```

So:

```
const n1 = new Number(123)
const n2 = new Number(123)
if (n1 === n2) {
  doSomethingImportant()
  // expected this to run, never does.
}
```

One expects two identical numbers to be equal according to the `===` operator, but if at least one is a `Number` object, then that's not true, and your code probably breaks somewhere. So it's worth guarding against.

On the other hand, lets say you did expect that:

```
const n1: Number = 123
const n2: Number = 123
if (n1 === n2) {
   throw new Error('never expected this to happen!')
   // expected this NOT to run, but it does
}
```

Now you could argue that's just as wrong. But here's the thing:

**The amount of code in the world that checks for numerical value equivalence *vastly* dwarfs the amount of code that expects two `Number` objects to not have the same identity.**

This means that this is *astronomically* less likely to be a bug.

And this is why `number` is a assignable to `Number`.

---

Like many things in Typescript, I believe this is a tradeoff between purity and pragmatism. And the *vast majority* of the time using a `number` as `Number` will cause no problems, where going the other way will break at least some very important behavior of how `number` is expected to behave.

Comment: I am not sure the statement that " number is a subtype of Number" is true.

Number is a subtype of type object. If number is a subtype of Number then number has to be a subtype of object too. But you cannot assign a number to an object.

Comment: Maybe "And this is why `number` is _assignable to_ `Number`" would be a better sentence there, because it's true that the hierarchy isn't completely clear. And shenanigans like this are still allowed: https://tsplay.dev/WPzpZN. But again, Typescript isn't perfect in every circumstance.